# reduced buffer cache hits for a query causes random performance issues

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, oracle11g

We have an UPDATE in production(below) which processes more or less the same number of rows each day but with drastically different runtimes. Some days the query finishes in 2 minutes, while other days, the query might take 20 minutes. Per my analysis of the AWR data, the culprit was I/O wait time and whenever the query slows down, the cache hit ratio goes down due to increased physical reads.

The outline of the query itself is below:

```
update /*+ nologging parallel ( a 12 )  */ huge_table1 a  
set   col = 1
where  col1 > 'A'
  and    col2 < 'B'
  and    exists ( select /*+ parallel ( b 12 ) */ 1
                from   huge_table2 b
                where  b.col3 = a.col3 );
```

huge_table1 and huge_table2 contains about 100 million rows and the execution statistics are below:

```
Day     EXECUTIONS ELAPSED_TIME_S_1EXEC CPU_TIME_S_1EXEC IOWAIT_S_1EXEC ROWS_PROCESSED_1EXEC BUFFER_GETS_1EXEC  DISK_READS_1EXEC DIRECT_WRITES_1EXEC
------- ----------- -------------------- ---------------- -------------- -------------------- ----------------- ----------------- -------------------
      1           1              133.055           69.110         23.325          2178085.000       3430367.000         90522.000           42561.000
      2           1              123.580           65.020         20.282          2179404.000       3341566.000         86614.000           38925.000
      3           1             1212.762           72.800       1105.084          1982658.000       3131695.000        268260.000           38446.000
      4           1             1085.773           59.600        996.642          1965309.000       2954480.000        200612.000           26790.000
```

As seen above, the LIO has remained almost the same in each case, although the elapsed time has increased in the 3rd and 4th days due to increased IO waits, which if my assumption is correct was caused by increase in the PIO. Per Tom Kyte, tuning should be focused on reducing the LIO instead of PIO and as LIO reduces, so will PIO. But in this case, the LIO has been constant throughout, but the PIO has been varying significantly.

My question - What tuning strategy could be adopted here?

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean by LIO/PIO here but it seems strange that you're concentrating on the query and tuning strategies.

You _know_ that the query isn't the problem. From the information provided I agree with your analysis, your issue is I/O waits. So, why do you have such long waits? As the query isn't the problem what environmental factors might be causing this? What else is running at the same time?

Comment: LIO/PIO are Logical/Physical reads respectively. I've checked and nothing significant(i.e long running/waits) other than this UPDATE is running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

-> Check the execution plan for both cases.
-> Check IO subsystem health.
-> Monitor the server the time this runs and make sure the IO sybsystem is not saturated by another process.

Also, what kind of I/O is leading read events? Sequential, parallel , scattered?... here you can ge a lead of the strategy the plan is following to perform the update...

Is the buffer cache being resized? a small and cold buffer cache which gets resized during this big execution could lead to blocks needing to be read into the buffer cache in order to update them.

Some ideas based on the data you showed... please let us know what came out!

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have checked the plans they have not changed and the I/O load during the time this query was run was not very high(the peak was about 10x times high). I cannot check the session level leading read events but at the system level it is db sequential read.

Comment: I didnt get this clear, can you tell:

1.- What are I/O , CPU , Memory statistics when good and bad performance.

2.- System level lead by sequential reads, where are you getting this from? I am assuming AWR, if this is the case can you share top 5 events from the AWR report.

3.- Session level, you should be able to get the ASH report for the same snapshots that you got awr for, ashrpt.sql under $ORACLE_HOME/admin/ I believe...

4.- If possible... this would be the best, if you can get to perform   extended sql trace for both good and bad performance, this will get you the answer str8 away.

Comment: I ran out of space for last comment. Extended sql trace also known as trace 10046 level 12 is production safe, just make sure you enable it only for the session that is running this query and you should have no problems. Please let me know the outcome!

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, but I have some interesting insights from the AWR data. Will let you all know if we ever solve this thing.

Comment: Whenever I face this kind of things, the easiest way is always observation between bad and good periods :). It takes a while but you will get it eventually, always focusing one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had problem which huge update. I found good solution based on parallel pipelined function which decrease time of updating significantly.
My proposition is not exactly what you asked but maybe this approach could give you short and stable time in days perspective:

1. Create type:

   ```
   CREATE type test_num_arr AS TABLE of INTEGER;
   /
   ```
2. Make updating pipelined function (you can ofcourse adjust):

   ```
   create or replace FUNCTION test_parallel_update (
   test_cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR
   ) 
   RETURN test_num_arr
   PARALLEL_ENABLE (PARTITION test_cur BY ANY)
   PIPELINED
   IS
   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;

   test_rec HUGE_TABLE1%ROWTYPE;
   TYPE num_tab_t IS TABLE OF NUMBER(38);

   pk_tab NUM_TAB_T;

   cnt INTEGER := 0;
   BEGIN
   LOOP
       FETCH test_cur BULK COLLECT INTO pk_tab LIMIT 1000;
       EXIT WHEN pk_tab.COUNT() = 0;

       FORALL i IN pk_tab.FIRST .. pk_tab.LAST
           UPDATE HUGE_TABLE1
           set   col = 1
           where  col1 > 'A'
           and    col2 < 'B'
           and    exists ( select 1
                           from   huge_table2 b
                           where  b.col3 = a.col3 
                          )
           AND ID = pk_tab(i);

       cnt := cnt + pk_tab.COUNT;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE test_cur;

   COMMIT;
   PIPE ROW(cnt);
   RETURN;
   END;
   ```
3. Lastly, run your update:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_parallel_update(CURSOR(SELECT id FROM huge_table1)));
   ```

Approach based on:
http://www.orafaq.com/node/2450

Comment: Thanks for your time. That is a nice use of PIPE functionality but I don't know if it will help to reduce the I/O. Nevertheless the benchmark results are impressive considering it goes against Tom's mantra: "You should do it in a single SQL statement if at all possible." http://tkyte.blogspot.in/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html Although to be fair, that is parallel MERGE and not a parallel UPDATE.

Comment: Re-read that article again carefully.  It is *not* saying that parallel pipelined functions are faster than parallel DML.  The case where the pipelined function is faster is caused by a different degree of parallelism.  Obviously if things run with a different DOP the performance will be different.  That website is usually reliable but this article is very misleading.  Tom's mantra is still true.

Comment: jonearles: Yep you are right, I wasn't reading between the lines. :-)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about the strategy, must of course choose LIO. Row access in buffer are much faster than disk operation.

With respect to your problem,seen that the first days the execution time is good and the last days it is not.
If you use indexes on columns = b.col3 a.col3 and there is a lot of insertion in the tables.Maybe they are out of date and so your query can no longer use the index and reads more blocks.
Because in your execution plan we see an increase in disk reads.

In this case it would be necessary to :

EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats(schema, table_name);

You should gather statistics periodically with scheduler. depending on your data changing on volume.

You could schedule during the day just a gathers index statistics with :

`DBMS_STATS.GATHER_INDEX_STATS`

And evening :

DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS

witch gathers table and column (and index) statistics.

In addition to your question about the possibilities there is also change to the data model. On large volumes partitioned tables are a good aproach in reducing IO.

hoping that ca can help

Comment: The OP is using Oracle 11g; stats are gathered overnight automatically.

Comment: if you speak about AutoTask it's just enabled by default. It does not mean that The OP did not deactivated.

Comment: Bertrand Ring: Ben is correct, we have the STATS collected automatically and up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

As bubooal says,  we can't help you whithout execution plan and table structure of the 2 tables.  Could you give us this 2 information?

Maybe partitioning could help you to reduce I/O.

Another possibilities is to keep the two table in your cache. it seems that the number of buffer get is the same. So when the query hangs it's because your tables are not in the buffer cache. For that you could use the db_keep_cache_size and pin your tables (or the good partition) in this cache